# How to correctly compose requests to the Unity server

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

good afternoon! How to correctly make requests to the server for this API in Unity? in particular I'm interested in Mint / burn

https://docs.openvessel.io/integration/EZzgG67O9oXGl9CReheF/game-api/tokens

https://game-api.stage.openvessel.io/docs/ui/swagger-ui/index.html#/

this example doesn't work

```
IEnumerator Upload()
{
    MintTokin mintTokin = new MintTokin();
    mintTokin.to = walletAddress;
    mintTokin.amount = 10;
    var json = JsonUtility.ToJson(mintTokin);

    var request = new UnityWebRequest("https://game-api.openvessel.io//tokens/manage/com.stage.mv-game.mv-collection.mv-item/mint", "POST");
    byte[] bodyRaw = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
    request.uploadHandler = (UploadHandler)new UploadHandlerRaw(bodyRaw);
    request.downloadHandler = (DownloadHandler)new DownloadHandlerBuffer();
    request.SetRequestHeader("X-Auth-Key", acesToken);
    request.SetRequestHeader("X-OpenVessel-Request-Id", "ab62663d-1645-4026-ba2d-d888b9634de9");
    yield return request.SendWebRequest();

    if (request.error != null)
    {
        Debug.Log("Erro: " + request.error);
        _statusText.text = request.error;
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("All OK");
        Debug.Log("Status Code: " + request.downloadHandler.text);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**It is strongly not recommended to use it in any game as it can cause uncontrolled access to your studio wallet. Mint should be done via the Vessel dashboard.**
*X-Auth-Key is the private key associated with your studio ERC-20 wallet.*

The following steps should help you:

- Double-check if *{fqTn}* is created in the Vessel dashboard.
- The value of the *X-Auth-Key* shouldn't start with the "0x" prefix, as it is shown in the example here https://game-api.stage.openvessel.io/docs/ui/swagger-ui/index.html#/03%20Tokens/mintToken
- The POST URL for calling mint should be on the staging environment, and no double slash after it. It should look like [https://game-api.stage.openvessel.io/tokents/manage/{fqTn}/mint](https://game-api.stage.openvessel.io/tokents/manage/%7BfqTn%7D/mint)
- The other problem is X-OpenVessel-Request-Id; it should be a unique GUID per each request, not a hardcoded one. With the current code snippet, you will get the "The given request ID is not unique" error.